# Copy group membership from one user to another in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im tyring to build a script which will copy group memberships from one user to another in AD. Im trying to use powershell to automate this task. However im stuck while creating a check for the user. In other words when i copy group membership from one user to another i want to be able to run a check to see if the user is already a member of the group before adding them, bu doing this i can avoid errors which such as " this user is already a member of the group and cannot be added again" Any help or advice would be appreciated. Im using the following to script at the moment.

```
$copy = Read-host "Enter user to copy from"
$Sam  = Read-host " Enter user to copy to"
 Function Copymembership {

$members = Get-ADUser -Identity $copyp -Properties memberof
foreach ($groups in $members.memberof){
if ($members -notcontains $groups.sAMAccountname)
{Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groups -Member $sam -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Output $groups} 
}
}
copymembership
```

Answer (score 14):

Use Get-ADUser for both users. Then use the -notcontains operator to filter groups.

```
$CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser JSmith -prop MemberOf
$CopyToUser = Get-ADUser MAdams -prop MemberOf
$CopyFromUser.MemberOf | Where{$CopyToUser.MemberOf -notcontains $_} |  Add-ADGroupMember -Member $CopyToUser
```

Comment: Correction in 2019 -- I had to user the parameter "Memebers" instead of "Member" 
               $CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser JSmith -prop MemberOf
$CopyToUser = Get-ADUser MAdams -prop MemberOf
$CopyFromUser.MemberOf | Where{$CopyToUser.MemberOf -notcontains $_} |  Add-ADGroupMember -Members $CopyToUse

Answer (score 10):

One line to get what the user member of.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity alan0 -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof
```

One line to copy the membership from one user to another.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity <UserID> -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |  Add-ADGroupMember -Members <New UserID>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is too complicated for this idea. Not sure if it can be done without the Active Directory module

It is much easier to do that when you import the ActiveDirectory tool and use the built-in cmdlet. Check my code:

```bash
# import the Active Directory module in order to be able to use Get-ADUser and Add-ADGroupMember cmdlet
import-Module ActiveDirectory

# enter login name of the first user
$copy = Read-host "Enter username to copy from: "

# enter login name of the second user
$paste  = Read-host "Enter username to copy to: "

# copy-paste process. Get-ADuser membership     | then selecting membership                       | and add it to the second user
get-ADuser -identity $copy -properties memberof | select-object memberof -expandproperty memberof | Add-AdGroupMember -Members $paste
```

Comment: PowerShell since version 3 does implicit module import, aka "module auto-loading." [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878284(v=vs.85).aspx#Anchor_3)

Comment: @Igor yes, I notice that when I'm on Active Directory server. But if you try to run the script from your station (considering that you have ADtool installed) - is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should tell you if a group contains a specific member:

```
If ((Get-ADGroup "Domain Admins" -Properties Members).Members -Contains (Get-ADUser "AdminBob").DistinguishedName) {write-host "Yes"}
```

There might be something simpler but this was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

param 
  (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$CopyFromUser,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$CopyToUser
  )

```
    $FromUserGroups = (Get-ADUser $CopyFromUser -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf
    $CopyToUser = Get-ADUser $CopyToUser -Properties MemberOf
    $FromUserGroups | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $CopyToUser
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have manual control on what groups are added, then this is perfect example for **Out-GridView**. Procedure is the same as explained by TheMadTechnician above, just before passing it to Add-ADGroupMember, you insert Out-GridView. You can even include group descriptions or other parameters.

```
$CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser JSmith -prop MemberOf
$CopyToUser = Get-ADUser MAdams -prop MemberOf

$MissingGroups = Compare-Object $CopyFromUser $CopyToUser -Property MemberOf | ? SideIndicator -eq '<='

$GroupsObj = $MissingGroups.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup –prop Description | Select Name,Description

$GroupsObj | Out-GridView -PassThru | Add-ADGroupMember -Member $CopyToUser
```

Answer (score 0):

am trying build script to Copy group membership from one user to another in AD
i have one domain and 3 different subdomains, can you please check if there is anything in the script must be changed, because it doesn't work thanks

```
$From = Read-Host -Prompt "From User"
$to = Read-Host -Prompt "To User"
$CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser -Server "de.isringhausen.net" -Identity $From -Properties MemberOf
$Group = $CopyFromUser.MemberOf
$confirmation = Read-Host "Do you want to Copy Group Membership from $From to $to ? Press 'y' to Proceed or any key to Cancel"
if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
    $Group | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $to
    clear
    echo "($From) User's Group Memership  has been Copied to User  ($to)"
Pause
}
else {
Write-Host 'Task Cancelled'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser JSmith -prop MemberOf
$CopyToUser = Get-ADUser MAdams -prop MemberOf

$MissingGroups = Compare-Object $CopyFromUser $CopyToUser -Property MemberOf | ? SideIndicator -eq '<='
$GroupsObj = $MissingGroups.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup –prop Description | Select Name ,Description
$Group2cp = $GroupsObj | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Select Goup to copy"
$Group2cp | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $CopyToUser
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).