# Filtering group memberships to copy from one user to another

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, active-directory-group

I currently have working code that copies all group memberships of one user to another, taken from here:
[Copy group membership from one user to another in AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754596/copy-group-membership-from-one-user-to-another-in-ad)

```
Get-ADuser $user_to_copy -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $user_name
```

I would like to add a filter which prevents groups that start with a number from being added.

For example:

123_Group - Would not be added to the new user.

Group_123 - Would be added to the new user.

I've been playing around with Where-Object but can't get it to work how I would like.

```
| Where-Object {$_.MemberOf -Match '[a-z]*'}
```

The groups have "CN=... etc." at the start which I've tried to account for as well but to no avail (no output errors, just not the output I need/expect). I'm not sure if I'm just making a mistake or should be attempting this another way.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use .NET's [Char.IsDigit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit) method to check if the first character of the name is a numerical digit:

```
Get-ADuser $user_to_copy -Properties MemberOf `
  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf `
  | Where-Object { -not [System.Char]::IsDigit($_[3]) } `
  | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $user_name
```

I use `$_[3]` (the fourth character) since the `memberOf` attribute is a list of `distinguishedName`, which will all start with `CN=` followed by the name of the group.

*Update:* If you want to filter out groups that start with a certain string, use something like this:

```
$badstring = "Computer"
Get-ADuser $user_to_copy -Properties MemberOf `
  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf `
  | Where-Object { -not $_.Substring(3).StartsWith($badstring) } `
  | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $user_name
```

Comment: This works perfectly for what I wanted, thank you.
However, how would one go about filtering beyond the first character, such as a group starting with a particular string like "Computer" or "January"? (I was hoping to use something like regex to be able to modify this for other requirements).

Comment: Wonderful, many thanks - that clears up my confusion completely!